# Find a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ of positive real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ of positive real numbers such that $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (a_{n+1}-a_n)=\infty$$ and $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(\sqrt{a_{n+1}}-\sqrt{a_n})=0.$$ I could not find such sequences. Any kind of help is required. Thank you.

If I find the solution later, then I shall post that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** $a_n=n^\beta$ for some appropriate $\beta$ should work.

Answer (score 1):

For example you can use $a_n=n^{3/2}$, or more generally $a_n=n^{s}$ with $1<s<2$.

Answer (score 1):

I found another answer. $a_n=n\ln n,\,n\ge1 $ satisfies the conditions.